# Column store indexes and nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2017, columnstore

I plan to store JSON documents in `nvarchar(max)` columns in a clustered column store indexed table in SQL Server 2017.

I have several contradicting information from vendor (Microsoft) whether it's a good idea or not:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-design-guidance?view=sql-server-2017

*Don't use a clustered columnstore index when:*

- The table requires `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)`, or `varbinary(max)` data types. Or, design the columnstore index so that it doesn't include these columns.

While the several other MS blog posts advertise the opposite:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/02/09/json-data-in-clustered-column-store-indexes/

There are even good tests in the latter post, but the first "Don't use ..." doesn't have anything to backup the statement.

Does anybody has experience what could go wrong? Or anybody uses such feature in production over millions of rows?

Comment: That experiment with storing JSON in a columnstore seems quite suspect to me. Crucially, it fails to test for speedup when just using regular table compression (`DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE`). Using a columnstore just for compressing text data seems like a huge waste to me -- the columnstore will still try to index and segment the contents of the rows, which is of no use whatsoever and pure overhead. The batch mode processing does add speedup, but you can have a table with page compression and squeeze batch mode out of that (automatic in 2019, with a hack in earlier versions).

Comment: A good question would be if you plan to actually index your documents -- that is, if you're going to be looking them up according to certain fixed portions in your JSON documents. You can use computed columns to [index JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/json/index-json-data), but columnstores don't allow computed columns (let alone indexes on them), so that's a significant limitation. As fast as columnstores are, without an index you'll still be scanning all of the data all the time.

Comment: The other crucial thing the CCI experiment doesn't account for is update/delete. If you're only ever going to append JSON data, a table with just one column will do fine. Otherwise, you're going to have to take the volume (and nature) of modifying transactions into account, as these things are more expensive on a columnstore than they are on a rowstore.

Comment: it might make more sense to use XML in SQL Server has SQL Server has native [XML indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-indexes-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @JeroenMostert No indexing is needed only storing and retrieving the whole json doc. Its an insert only table and would take advantage of the compression and the batch mode.

Comment: @RaymondNijland XML is stored as binary behind the scenes and cannot be really compressed and according to my measures it twice as slow to retrieve the whole documents from the db. The native indexes are nice, and I hope JSON will have native indexes soon in SQL server.

Comment: Well, like I said, I'd also test a table of the form `CREATE TABLE T(ID BIGINT IDENTITY, [data] NVARCHAR(MAX), CONSTRAINT PK_T_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ID) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE), INDEX IX_T_Dummy_CS NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE(ID) WHERE (ID IS NULL))`. This is a regular rowstore with page compression that uses a dummy columnstore index to profit from batch mode "for free", leaving open the option of using computed columns to index your JSON. I haven't tested the perf characteristics of this, though (they will vary by scenario anyway, of course).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, interesting idea of dummy CI here. I will need to test performance there. Still its interesting tot see how convincing the 2nd blog post is with good test cases.

Comment: I'd have thought it a much better post if the author addressed the obvious elephants in the room with regards to the different scenarios you might typically face and the other options for compression, but as a "here's how you could make things faster in newer versions of SQL Server without changing anything on your end" good news post it does its job, I suppose. :-P There are legitimate concerns to address with storing `NVARCHAR(MAX)` columns in columnstores, and neither "it's always bad" nor "it's just a good idea period" really cover it.

Comment: *"XML is stored as binary behind the scenes and cannot be really compressed and according to my measures it twice as slow to retrieve the whole documents from the db"* @Avithohol very surprised to hear that, no shocked is more the correct word.. Full or parts scanning from Binairy XML (when correctly implemented) would/should be (much) faster vs text XML in thoery...  W3C didn't invent Efficient XML Interchange (EXI) for nothing.

Comment: *"XML is stored as binary behind the scenes and cannot be really compressed and according to my measures it twice as slow to retrieve the whole documents from the db"* if that true as i don't know how you benchmarked it  @Avithohol but most likely the Binairy to text on the fly conversion is most likely what caused the slowdown you have measured.. ..

Answer (score 1):

**Limitations and Restrictions of Columnstore Indexes** 
Cannot include large object (LOB) columns of type `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` in non-clustered column store indexes. Only clustered columnstore indexes support LOB types, beginning in `SQL Server 2017 (14.x)` version and Azure SQL Database configured at Premium tier, Standard tier (S3 and above), and all VCore offerings tiers tier. Note, prior versions do not support LOB types in clustered and nonclustered columnstore indexes.

[souce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#LimitRest)

Comment: So what can we use? instead of (max) can I specify numeric value of max?